# WSO2 esb duplicate SOAP envelope tag

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

**I created Proxy Service in WSO2 ESB, with xst transformation and when i to send request from esb i watch in logs next response from service:**

```
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
 "[0x9]<soap:Header/>" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[0x9]<soap:Body> <m:putResponse xmlns:m="http://www.lmsoftmdm.ru">[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[0x9]<m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[0x9][0x9][0x9]xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[0x9][0x9]<m:isError>true</m:isError>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
{org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[0x9]</m:return>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
{org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "</m:putResponse></soap:Body>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "</soap:Envelope>'
```

**But ESB change it before sending:**

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[0x9]<soap:Header></soap:Header>[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[0x9]<soap:Body> <m:putResponse xmlns:m="http://www.lmsoftmdm.ru">[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[0x9]<m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[0x9][0x9]<m:isError>true</m:isError>[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[0x9]</m:return>[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "</m:putResponse></soap:Body>[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-05 18:45:24,018] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "</soap:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this problem?
thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't fix this for you if we can't see what causes it. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

This because you have used soap envelope with in your xslt style sheet.
what ESB does is , It only pass the body elements to xslt mediator. so you can only manipulate the body elements using xslt mediator not the soap envelope or soap header. so  after xslt transformation,transformed content will be added to body of the original soap. so if you have soap envelop in your transformation , that will be considered as body part. so use xslt mediator to only manipulate the body and use enrich mediator to manipulate the soap envelope